# Cannot locate source?

Tags: android

so, i've been working on this same stupid thing for a while now. some folks here have helped me get it to the point it is but now i've got to move farther forward... but first, my code:

```
package com.mhe.test.scan;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class main extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button myScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myScanButton);

    totalbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tBox);        

    myScanButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);






      }
    });
  }      
  private EditText totalbox;
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      final String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");




        if ( totalbox != null );


        totalbox.setText(contents);


        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Successful Scan";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        Button myTotalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myTotalButton);
        myTotalButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view)  {
                Intent pass = new Intent(view.getContext(), Result.class);
                    startActivityForResult(pass, 0);
               }
            });



      } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        if ( totalbox != null );
          totalbox.setText("bummer");
      }      

    }




  }
}
```

so anyhow, what i'd like to happen is upon a successful scan, the result is loaded into the EditText totalbox. then the 'myTotalButton' is clicked and will pass the result to the next activity 'Result.class'. right now i'm just trying to get it to switch to the new activity. If the
    `Button myTotalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myTotalButton);
        myTotalButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view)  {
            Intent pass = new Intent(view.getContext(), Result.class);
                    startActivityForResult(pass, 0);`

code is there, it FCs. otherwise, the rest of it works fine. any suggestions/assistance would be helpful. I feel like i am missing something stupid that i will smack myself for.

Comment: What does Logcat show for the reason behind the FC?

Comment: 07-07 14:25:44.146: INFO/ActivityManager(1083): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.mhe.test.scan/.Result }
07-07 14:25:45.193: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1083): GC_EXPLICIT freed 789 objects / 38656 bytes in 137ms
07-07 14:25:45.224: ERROR/Tethering(1083): active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
07-07 14:25:48.740: WARN/WindowManager(1083): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
07-07 14:25:49.271: WARN/WindowManager(1083): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
07-07 14:25:53.154: INFO/ActivityManager(1083): Start proc 

thats the verbose logcat

Comment: and this looks like where the error is... though i've really no idea what to do with this 


07-07 14:24:45.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2857): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException


it also mentions a class not found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just realized what the problem is.

The button press activity calls back into the same `onActivityResult` method it's called from, and using the same requestCode of 0. This is causing the errors where you attempt to `getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT")` because that only exists in the callback from the scan.

Instead of `startActivityForResult(pass, 0);` use `startActivityForResult(pass, 1);` (or whatever digit) and handle it by adding an

```
} else if (1 == requestCode) {
    \* your stuff to handle the button result here*\
}
```

code section to the existing requestCode if statement (or make it a switch() statement).

The end result would look something like this:

```
@Override 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            if ( totalbox != null ) {
                totalbox.setText(contents);
            }

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Successful Scan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Button myTotalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myTotalButton);
            myTotalButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent pass = new Intent(view.getContext(), Result.class);
                    startActivityForResult(pass, 1);
                   }
                });
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if ( totalbox != null ) {
                totalbox.setText("bummer");
            }
        }
    } else if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Do whatever it is you want to do with the returned
            // data from the Result.class activity call
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my newbie self is still trying to implement this but it looks like the right course of action. any further assistance would be appreciated but i'm taking this answer.

Comment: Glad I could help! I updated the answer to include a more thorough code example (which I cleaned up a bit as well).

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the new activity to your Manifest? 
Also, have you included the intent integrator code from the zxing project?

Comment: yes and i am actually calling the barcode scanner app via intent. scan is successful

Answer (score 0):

So, am I correct in thinking that you just want to pass a result on to another activity? If so, there is an easy Java way of doing it that is non Android specific. If so, then let me know and I'll help.

Comment: yes, thats exactly it, and i want it to happen when i click the myTotalButton